# Passing variable in ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the variable $id inside the scope. I want to pass it into the function "createPNG" and in this function i want to use this ID to access the downloadContainer.

```
<button type="button" ng-click="createPNG('{{$id}}')">Create Image</button>
<div ng-attr-id="downloadContainer_{{$id}}"></div>
```

Angular correctly translates the downloadContainer_{{$id}} to the correct number but the function only passes the string {{$id}}. In an older angularJS Version I did not have this problem.

Comment: you are passing a string literal, denoted by single quotes into your function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply replace with

```
<button type="button" ng-click="createPNG($id)">Create Image</button>
```

Comment: So simple. Thanks. it was different in earlier versions of angular.